# Vue vue-sweetalert2 . error in test:unit with Jest

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vue-sweetalert2

As per the [vue-sweetalert2](https://github.com/avil13/vue-sweetalert2) doc, in my `main.js`, I import and use the plugin:

```
import VueSweetalert2 from "vue-sweetalert2";
Vue.use(VueSweetalert2);
```

In my component, `ContactForm.vue`, I can use:

```
this.$swal(...)
```

However, when I test:unit this component, I need to add the import and `Vue.use()`

```
 import VueSweetalert2 from "vue-sweetalert2";
 Vue.use(VueSweetalert2);
```

and I get an error:

```
$ vue-cli-service test:unit ContactForm.spec.js
```

FAIL  tests/unit/ContactForm.spec.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

/Users/yves/Developments/WIP/VUE.JS-cli-3/3-chocha-home-content/chocha/node_modules/vue-sweetalert2/src/index.js:2
import swal from 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.js';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

What could be wrong?

**UPDATE**

the `vue-sweetalert2/src/index.js`, line 2 faulty line, is:

```
// @ts-check
import swal from 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.js';
```

the developer of this wrapper added an `index.d.ts` fie

```
import Vue, { PluginObject, PluginFunction } from 'vue';
import * as swal from 'sweetalert2';
...
```

but it seems not to be taken in account.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED ...

I added a transformIgnorePatterns in my jest config in package.json

```
     "jest": {
    ....
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/(?!vue-sweetalert2).+\\.js$"
    ],
    ....
  }
```